# 1+AB=1 using boolean algebra ? Am I right or not?

Tags: boolean-algebra

As 1+AB 
Now if I put A=0 & B=1 then the above expression gives the answer 1 
Conversely if I put A=1 & B=0  then again the answer of above expression is 1
I've seen manly rules or laws to solve boolean algebra problems but I didn't see anyone like this so I'm not sure wether I'm right or wrong please guide me thanks in advance

Comment: Note that $True$ $or$ $something = True$.

Comment: Since $1+1 = 1$ and $1+0 = 1$ we must have $1+X = 1$ regardless of $X$.

Comment: $1+A=1$ is called Annihilation or Dominance

Comment: The law you are looking for is [Annulment Law](https://www.mi.mun.ca/users/cchaulk/misc/boolean.htm)